# :INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hive, emr

I am using EMR services from Amazon Web Services and am attempting to run a count query on an external table that I've built. The data for the table is stored in mongodb and the table is an external table in Hive. The query I'm trying to run is

```
select user_id, count (*) from myTable group by user_id;
```

I can query select * from myTable but I cannot do any other queries. When I try to I get this error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        VERTICES      MODE        STATUS  TOTAL  COMPLETED  RUNNING  PENDING  FAILED  KILLED
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Map 1            container        FAILED     -1          0        0       -1       0       0
Reducer 2        container        KILLED      1          0        0        1       0       0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
VERTICES: 00/02  [>>--------------------------] 0%    ELAPSED TIME: 0.03 s
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Status: Failed
Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:3986)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$3100(VertexImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:2818)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2765)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
        at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:59)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1888)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2242)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2228)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:183)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:114)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://ip-172-31-33-88.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/8c1eca9a-84ba-4d79-b39c-e633f1c6a646/hive_2016-10-14_18-57-38_728_4862537458701624850-1/hadoop/_tez_scratch_dir/157c0e27-0bfa-4acf-b0e9-b2fed595a8de/map.xml: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat
Serialization trace:
inputFileFormatClass (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc)
aliasToPartnInfo (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:298)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:131)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat
Serialization trace:
inputFileFormatClass (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc)
aliasToPartnInfo (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:156)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClass(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$ClassSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:326)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$ClassSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:314)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObjectOrNull(SerializationUtilities.java:198)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:132)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:175)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:213)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:583)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:469)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:411)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
        ... 55 more
]
Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]
DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezTask. Vertex failed, vertexName=Map 1, vertexId=vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_00, diagnostics=[Vertex vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_00 [Map 1] killed/failed due to:INIT_FAILURE, Fail to create InputInitializerManager, org.apache.tez.dag.api.TezReflectionException: Unable to instantiate class with 1 arguments: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.createClazzInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:89)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager$1.run(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.createInitializer(RootInputInitializerManager.java:148)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.RootInputInitializerManager.runInputInitializers(RootInputInitializerManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.setupInputInitializerManager(VertexImpl.java:3986)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.access$3100(VertexImpl.java:204)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.handleInitEvent(VertexImpl.java:2818)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2765)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl$InitTransition.transition(VertexImpl.java:2747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMachineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
        at org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez.doTransition(StateMachineTez.java:59)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:1888)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.dag.impl.VertexImpl.handle(VertexImpl.java:203)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2242)
        at org.apache.tez.dag.app.DAGAppMaster$VertexEventDispatcher.handle(DAGAppMaster.java:2228)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher.java:183)
        at org.apache.tez.common.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.java:114)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tez.common.ReflectionUtils.getNewInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:68)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load plan: hdfs://ip-172-31-33-88.ec2.internal:8020/tmp/hive/hadoop/8c1eca9a-84ba-4d79-b39c-e633f1c6a646/hive_2016-10-14_18-57-38_728_4862537458701624850-1/hadoop/_tez_scratch_dir/157c0e27-0bfa-4acf-b0e9-b2fed595a8de/map.xml: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat
Serialization trace:
inputFileFormatClass (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc)
aliasToPartnInfo (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:451)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getMapWork(Utilities.java:298)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.HiveSplitGenerator.<init>(HiveSplitGenerator.java:131)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Unable to find class: com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat
Serialization trace:
inputFileFormatClass (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.PartitionDesc)
aliasToPartnInfo (org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.plan.MapWork)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:156)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:133)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClass(Kryo.java:670)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClass(SerializationUtilities.java:180)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$ClassSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:326)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultSerializers$ClassSerializer.read(DefaultSerializers.java:314)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObjectOrNull(Kryo.java:759)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObjectOrNull(SerializationUtilities.java:198)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:132)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readClassAndObject(Kryo.java:790)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readClassAndObject(SerializationUtilities.java:175)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:161)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.MapSerializer.read(MapSerializer.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:213)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.ObjectField.read(ObjectField.java:125)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.FieldSerializer.read(FieldSerializer.java:551)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.readObject(Kryo.java:686)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities$KryoWithHooks.readObject(SerializationUtilities.java:205)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializeObjectByKryo(SerializationUtilities.java:583)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:492)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SerializationUtilities.deserializePlan(SerializationUtilities.java:469)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Utilities.getBaseWork(Utilities.java:411)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.input.HiveMongoInputFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.hive.com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.DefaultClassResolver.readName(DefaultClassResolver.java:154)
        ... 55 more
]Vertex killed, vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_01, diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill in NEW state., Vertex vertex_1476467351971_0008_2_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE. failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1
hive>
```

I am using a single node EMR cluster from AWS with the "Core Hadoop" configuration, but I had the same errors using a three node cluster. I have already added the Mongo Hadoop Core, Mongo Hadoop Hive, Mongo Java driver to the master node.. These are the jars I'm using:

```
mongo-hadoop-hive-2.0.1.jar
mongo-java-driver-3.3.0.jar 
remotecontent?filepath=org%2Fmongodb%2Fmongo-hadoop%2Fmongo-hadoop-core%2F2.0.1%2Fmongo-hadoop-core-2.0.1.jar
```

These jars were downloaded from Maven.

A similar question had previously been asked on StackOverflow and was resolved by adding the src for Apache Tez 0.8.4 and building it. Apache Tez 0.8.4 is already on the cluster though, at least according to the EMR configuration we chose.

We are using Hadoop 2.7.2 and Hive 2.1.0.

Comment: Hi AMV,
were you able to resolve this issue? Please let us know. Thanks.